# Is there a way to set color of label inline code?

Tags: java, colors, label

I have trying to make a leaderboard where it will simply display a few label's located within a GridPane. However, as my background is a dark blue, it is difficult to see the default text colour as it is grey. Is there anyway to set the colour while i define the label?

Given I will have multiple label's, this is why i have defined the label without an object variable. Therefore, I am not able to use an object as it would make duplicate ones on the next loop.

```
int rowCount = 1;
for (HighScore score : scores) {
    endGameLayout.add((new Label(score.name)).setTextFill(Color.WHITE), 0, rowCount);
    endGameLayout.add(new Label(score.date.toString()), 1, rowCount);
    endGameLayout.add(new Label(score.result.toString()), 2, rowCount);
    endGameLayout.add(new Label(score.elapsedTime.toString()), 3, rowCount);
    rowCount++;
}
```

Is there anyway of defining the colour of the label within the definition?

Comment: Why not create a private method that returns a `Label`? Something like: `private Label createLable(String text) { /* create, configure, return */ }`.

Comment: Yup this works nicely, thanks a lot!